# Return most frequent letter lowercase and in alphabetical order

Tags: python, string, list, function

This is the problem that I found on internet.
mostFrequentLetter(s)
Takes a string, s, and returns a lowercase string that contains the most frequently occurring letter(s) in alphabetical order. Case should be ignored (so "A" and "a" are considered the same for this function). Only letters are to be considered (no punctuation or whitespace). You do not need to worry about how efficient this function is.

So far I have this:

```
def mostFrequentLetter(s):        
    s1 = sorted(s)    
    s1 = s.lower()       
    for x in s1:
        if s1.isAlpha == True:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The most frequent letters

```
from collections import Counter

def mostFrequentLetter(s):
    mc = Counter(c for c in s.lower() if c.isalpha()).most_common()
    return ''.join(sorted(c[0] for c in mc if c[1] == mc[0][1]))
```

Examples:

```
>>> mostFrequentLetter("ZgVhyaBbv")
'bv'
>>> mostFrequentLetter("aaabbcc????")
'a'
```

### The `n` most frequent letters

This will provide the `n` most frequent letters in string `s`, sorted in alphabetical order:

```
from collections import Counter

def mostFrequentLetter(s, n=1):
    ctr = Counter(c for c in s.lower() if c.isalpha())
    return ''.join(sorted(x[0] for x in ctr.most_common(n)))
```

Examples:

```
>>> mostFrequentLetter('aabbccadef?!', n=1)
'a'
>>> mostFrequentLetter('aabbccadef?!', n=3) 
'abc'
```

#### How it works

- `c for c in s.lower() if c.isalpha()`

  This converts string `s` to lower case and then just the letters from that string.
- `ctr = Counter(c for c in s.lower() if c.isalpha())`

  This creates a Counter instance for those letters.  We will use the method `most_common` to select the most common letters.  To get the three most common letters, for example, we can use:

  ```
  >>> data.most_common(3)
  [('a', 3), ('c', 2), ('b', 2)]
  ```

  In our case, we are not interested in the counts, only the letters, so we have to manipulate this output.
- `x[0] for x in ctr.most_common(n)`

  This selects the `n` most common letters.
- `sorted(x[0] for x in ctr.most_common(n))`

  This sorts alphabetically the `n` most common letters.
- `return ''.join(sorted(x[0] for x in ctr.most_common(n)))`

  This joins most common letters back into a string and returns them.

### The most frequent letters without using packages

If we can't use `collections.Counter`, then try:

```
def mostFrequentLetter(s):
    d = {}
    for c in s.lower():
        d[c] = d.get(c, 0) + 1
    mx = max(dict_values())
    return sorted(c for c, v in d.items() if v == mx)
```

Comment: I think he wants to know exactly how your counter is doing the process

Comment: def mostFrequentLetter(s, n=1):
but is there a way to do it with out n=1? Because the problem that i found online only uses defmostFrequentLetter(s)

Comment: Also i need to return the letter or letters that repeats the most.
for example:
mostFrequentLetter("ZgVhyaBbv") == "bv")

Comment: @Aleish OK.  Code for that is now in the answer.

Comment: @John1024 Sorry, but do you know any other way where i won't need to use Counter

Comment: @Aleish I added a version that avoids using `Counter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def mostFrequentLetter(s):
    s1 = s.lower()
    new = set(s1)
    mod={}

    for item in new:
        if item.isalpha():
            mod[item]=s1.count(item)

    frequent = sorted (mod,key = mod.get)
    return list(reversed(frequent))
```

Comment: it works but it can only print one letter. The code supposed to print more than one letter as well.

Comment: It would be nice to explain why this helps.